# Include a conditionalPanel in a Shiny module with condition based on global input

Tags: r, module, shiny, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a Shiny module which shows a conditionalPanel based on input from the global UI. In the minimal example below the conditionalPanel should show a radioButtons widget when a checkbox in the global UI is clicked, but I can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
library(shiny)

conditional <- function(input, output, session, check){
  output$check <- reactive({check()})
  outputOptions(output, "check", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  output$conditional <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = 'output.check',
      radioButtons(ns('radioItem'),
                   'Select option',
                   choices = c('option 1','option 2'))
    )
  })

}

conditionalUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns('conditional'))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(checkboxInput('check','Show')),
  fluidRow(conditionalUI('mymod'))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  check <- reactive({input$check})
  callModule(conditional, 'mymod', check = check)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix - The condition should be `condition = input.check` instead of `condition = output.check`.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a problem with the naming conventions that shiny modules enforce.

Although you have a similar `output` object in your module, it is not the same as in `server`. If you specify an output

```
func <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$something <- (...)
}
```

inside a module, that you called with

```
callModule(func, 'someIdentifier')
```

then your output id, which shiny uses to reference all the elements, becomes

```
someIdentifier-something
```

You can test this by writing `uiOutput("mymod-conditional")` instead of `uiOutput(ns('conditional'))`.

Normally, this shouldn't bother you, since modules work the way that all references are resolved within a module. But the `conditionalPanel` condition, being in JavaScript ("on the other side" so to say), must use global references.

So the fix for your problem would be to change the condition to

```
condition = 'output["mymod-check"]'
```

Note that dashes cant be used with JavaScript dot notation, so bracket notation has to be used.

A trick that helped me identify the problem, was to inject JavaScript into the condition in order to show the current value of `output` on the client side. I placed `condition = 'console.log(output)'` inside the `conditionalPanel` so you can inspect the available object in the browser console.